# How to open unknown file type with specific app

Tags: android

Im trying to make video streams from kodi appear on my android tv recommendations section. Everything works fine but now I'm trying to open the stream directly in kodi. The file has a ".strm" extension.

I have tried this code:

`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("PATH TO THE .strm FILE");
        intent.setDataAndType(videoUri, "*/*");
        startActivity(intent);`

It shows a lot of options but kodi is not on the list. If I'm using a file explorer and open the ".strm" file I have the option to open it as video and then there is kodi in the list and if I click on kodi it directly opens the stream. So I concluded that it must be possible to force kodi to open the app but I can't figure out how file mangers do this.

I also tried "video/*" as MIME but it shows only a few video players while file mangers show a lot more video players.

How can I get the same options that a file manager shows for opening a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, I don't know if it's the correct way but it works. With the app "Activity Launcher" I looked what activities kodi has. Apparently it has only 1 activity named ".Splash".

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("PATH TO THE .strm FILE");
    intent.setDataAndType(videoUri, "*/*");
    intent.setClassName("org.xbmc.kodi", "org.xbmc.kodi.Splash");
    startActivity(intent);
```

For some reason setpackage didn't work but setclassname did work.